# EXCEL VBA replacing cell's content

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to replace a cell's text in case a condition is fullfilled, but the data is in another file. How can I do it?
I used something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim customerBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook


Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook


filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)


Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

If targetSheet.Range("Q19", "BL23").Text = "OK" Then
sourceSheet.Range("GB38", "GH38").Text = "Agreed"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the file type of the "other file"?

Comment: its another excel file

Comment: so actually where is the problem, do you get any error or ?

Comment: No, the cell's content doesn't change to "Agreed"

Comment: Turns out my code may be right, but the "OK" from the Q19-BL23 cell is not being detected

Comment: Finally got it, turns out the cell wasnt finding the "OK", and I already fixed it. Thanks for all the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Thanks for the support

```
Sub test()
Dim customerBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook


Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook


filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)


Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Dim x As String


If sourceSheet.Range("Q19").Text = "OK" Then
x = "Agreed"
End If

targetSheet.Range("GB38", "GH38") = x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the Update.

Answer (score 4):

You need to:

- test **Q19** and **BL23** separately
- use **.Value** rather than **.Text** since **.Text** is read-only

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the reason I suggest testing the cells separately.  Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
   MsgBox Range("C3,A1") = "X"
End Sub
```

On an empty worksheet, we get **False**
If we set **C3** to an *X* we get **True**
If we clear **C3** and set **A1** to an *X* we get **False**!

It turns out that for a dis-joint range, only the **first** element is examined........the others are ignored!

Comment: @Vasily  They CAN be tested as in the original code, but we need to understand if we want **True** to mean **both** cells contain *Ok* or if **either** cell contains *Ok* !!

Comment: Gary whenever I try to do that MsgBox Range it shows up an error: Error 13 Type mismatch

Comment: @DanielSantos  Post your updated code.............. *Error 13* are usually easy to fix.

Comment: ++ For explaining it :) Another way `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(targetSheet.Range("Q19", "BL23"), "OK") = 2 Then _
sourceSheet.Range("GB38", "GH38").Value = "Agreed"`

Comment: Your way of thinking got me to the bottom of the issue, Thanks @Gary'sStudent

Answer (score 2):

here an example how you can achieve replacement by condition

```
'''''
If targetSheet.[Q19, BL23].text= "ok" Then
    sourceSheet.Cells.Replace what:="Search string", replacement:="Replacement String"
End If
'''''
```

> the cell's content doesn't change to "Agreed"

here your updated code, but this is not replacement as written in title

```
''''''
If targetSheet.[Q19, BL23].text = "OK" Then
    sourceSheet.[GB38, GH38].Value = "Agreed"
End If
'''''
```

for verification of the multiple range content use `.text`, but to insert value in multiple range you need to use `.value`

test in screenshots below

**wrong way of the multiple range verification using `.value`**

[image]

**wrong way of the multiple range verification without specified range property**

[image]

**right way of the multiple range verification using `.text`**

[image]

Comment: @Gary'sStudent if you don't specify range property then vba will use `.value` by default, but my example shows you that with `.text` range property verification goes in another way, so you will receive true with `.text` range property only if both cells will be `"ok"`, please see my updated post

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
customerWorkbook.Close customerWorkbook.Saved = True
```

before your `End Sub` statement. That should fix it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it didn't

Comment: @DanielSantos Damn, I was sure that would fix it :\ Sorry to have wasted your time mate

Comment: Dont say sorry if you tried to help, what matters are the intentions xd (lame comment xd)